# Storing/managing PWA push notification subscription data for same user with multiple devices?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but every article/tutorial I've read about push notifications seems to be leaving this detail out.

For reference, [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push)'s `sendNotification` method accepts `pushSubscription`, `payload`, and `options`.

To send a notification to a user at any point in time, the user's `pushSubscription` data would need to be stored in a database and retrieved to be used as needed, right? So if the user has enabled push notifications for multiple devices, the `pushSubscription` data would need to be stored for each device.

I guess my question is... How do you know when e.g. a device is no longer in use so that you can delete the stale `pushSubscription` data? Or suppose, for whatever reason, the `PushManager` generates a new `pushSubscription` for the same user + device... How would you know to replace the old `pushSubscription` with the new one?

Is the solution to build a device manager for the user to manage each device and its associated push subscription(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this right -- a nice implementation is one where you show the browser(s) with push notifications enabled. Another way is you just prompt to enable push notifications if they aren't enabled in the current browser in use.

#### Stale: HTTP 410 Gone

I've found that when a push notification goes away, the push endpoint will return a HTTP 410 Gone status code. So if I get that in response to a push attempt, I remove that push entry.

#### Microsoft Edge rate limits with HTTP 406

On a side note, I found in practice that the Microsoft Edge push servers will often return a HTTP 406 Not Acceptable status code if you push too many notifications. So in a perfect world, in an app where many notifications were sent, we'd alert the user about that issue. Here is an example of that response:

```json
{
  "name": "WebPushError",
  "message": "Received unexpected response code",
  "statusCode": 406,
  "headers": {
    "content-length": "0",
    "retry-after": "900",
    "x-wns-notificationstatus": "appthrottled",
    "x-wns-status": "appthrottled",
    "x-wns-msg-id": "_redacted_",
    "x-wns-debug-trace": "_redacted_",
    "ms-cv": "_redacted_.0",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "date": "Fri, 21 Oct 2022 15:55:28 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "body": "",
  "endpoint": "https://wns2-bl2p.notify.windows.com/w/?token=_redacted_"
}
```

I was surprised to find there isn't really a lot of solid technical articles about implementing push notifications in the big picture. Once you get into the details, it's not too bad but it is definitely an area which could use more documentation and discussion.